# public method not visible in another class

Tags: c#, forms, class, label, public

I'm trying to implement a GameStateManager in a game I'm writing.

In my main form I have a label of which I'm trying to change the text from within a certain gameState.

Because I do not want to change the label to public, which is bad practice,  I did the following :

```
public void ChangeScoreLabel(string text)
{
    this.lblScore.Text = text;
}
```

I pass the mainform to my class with following code :

```
gameStateManager.Add("game", new CStateGame(gameStateManager, this));
```

Inside the game class in the constructor I pass it on :

```
public CStateGame(CStateManager gameStateManager, Form form)
{
    m_gameStateManager = gameStateManager;
    m_form = form;
}
```

and now this doesn't work :

```
m_form.ChangeScoreLabel("Score : " + iScore.ToString());
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Use `as` to cast parent `Form` class to your real `Form1` (or how you call it): `(m_form as Form1).ChangeScoreLabel("Score : " + iScore.ToString());`

Answer (score 1):

The type of `m_form` must be your concrete form. E.g., `MyForm m_form;` instead of `Form m_form;`. The same is true for the method parameter:

```
public CStateGame(CStateManager gameStateManager, MyForm form)
```

Your form is a class deriving from `Form`. But since `Form` does not declare `ChangeScoreLabel`, this method is not visible through a variable or property of type `Form`.

---

If it is not possible to change the type (e.g., because the method parameters, variables or properties are not under your control), then you must cast to your form type.

```
((MyForm)m_form).ChangeScoreLabel("Score : " + iScore.ToString());
```

or, safer

```
if (m_form is MyForm myForm) {
    myForm.ChangeScoreLabel("Score : " + iScore.ToString());
}
```